# Extend and override default lighthouse directive

Tags: overriding, directive, extend, laravel-lighthouse

Is there anyway that I can override a directive like: src/Schema/Directives/WhereDirective.php for instance this doesn't support some methods on my custom builder, I know I can make another directive and extend this like @myWhere but that's dirty, would be nice to be able to override the @where itself.

I've searched around but nothing was found about this sadly!

Comment: I already did something like this but I believe my way is dirtier than making a new directive. You must touch the composer.json file to manipulate the class mappings.

Comment: @mostafa Well thank you it might be dirty but sounds creative so it doesn't mean you can't post it as an answer and get an upvote ;) even though I won't probably be using it since I can't touch composer.json I'm making a library but still your way is creative and I liked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. according to https://lighthouse-php.com/5/custom-directives/getting-started.html#register-directives

> When Lighthouse encounters a directive within the schema, it starts looking for a matching class in the following order: 
> 1. User-defined namespaces as configured in config/lighthouse.php, defaults to App\GraphQL\Directives 
> 2. The RegisterDirectiveNamespaces event is dispatched to gather namespaces defined by plugins, extensions or other listeners 
>  3. Lighthouse's built-in directive namespace.

So it did seem like override could be possible, and it was.

I haven't tried first method (App\GraphQL\Directive...) but that  probably would work too, I went with the second method the `RegisterDirectiveNamespaces` event, since I was writing a package.

Make all your directives in the same folder under one namespace eg:

```php
namespace SteveMoretz\Something\GraphQL\Directives;
```

Now in a service provider (Can be your package's service provider or AppServiceProvider or any service provider you get the idea.) register that namespace your directives are under.

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Events\RegisterDirectiveNamespaces;

class ScoutGraphQLServiceProvider {
    public function register(Dispatcher $dispatcher) {
        $dispatcher->listen(
            RegisterDirectiveNamespaces::class,
            static function (): string {
                return "SteveMoretz\Something\GraphQL\Directives";
            }
        );
    }
}
```

That's it so for an example I have overridden the `@where` directive, first I created a file named as original `WhereDirective.php` then put these contents in it:

```php
<?php

namespace SteveMoretz\Something\GraphQL\Directives;

use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Scout\ScoutBuilderDirective;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\ArgBuilderDirective;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Directives\BaseDirective;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Directives\WhereDirective as WhereDirectiveOriginal;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\FieldResolver;

class WhereDirective extends WhereDirectiveOriginal
{
    public function handleBuilder($builder, $value): object
    {
        $clause = $this->directiveArgValue('clause', 'where');

        // do some other stuff too... my custom logic 

        return $builder->{$clause}(
            $this->directiveArgValue('key', $this->nodeName()),
            $this->directiveArgValue('operator', '='),
            $value
        );
    }
}
```

Now whenever we use `@where` my custom directive runs instead of the original one, but be careful what you do in this directive don't alter the whole directive try to extend the original and add more options to it, otherwise you would end up confusing yourself later!

Answer (score 1):

I edit my composer.json and manipulate the class mappings. In this example, I wanted to override some cache classes.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
        "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Cache\\": "lighthouseV6/cache/"
    },
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Cache/CacheKeyAndTags.php",
        "vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Cache/CacheKeyAndTagsGenerator.php",
        "vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Cache/CacheDirective.php"
    ]
},
```

Then create a folder "lighthouseV6/cache" in the root of the project and copy the classes I wanted to override from "vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Cache" inside it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this for a cleaner solution check my answer, I specially wrote it for you.